# Barchart more practical

Tags: charts

Is there any more specific function to achieve this same result?

```
list={410, 1265, 2262, 2255, 3828, 6739, 15566, 12210}
BarChart[Apply [Labeled, Reverse [Transpose [{Range [Length[list]], list}], 2], {1}]]
```

Comment: What does "more specific" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BarChart @ MapIndexed[Labeled[#, #2[[1]]] &, list]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
BarChart @ Thread[Labeled[list, Range @ Length @ list]] (* or *)
BarChart[list, ChartLabels -> Range[Length @ list]]
```

> same picture